# Архитектура приложения JAVA FX, AWT, RMI

Tags: javafx, архитектура, awt, jfree

Для научного desktop приложения появилась необходимость использовать библиотеку графиков JFreeChart именно под AWT, так как под java fx при большом количестве отображаемых данных приложение тормозит, но при этом для остальной части интерфейса хочется использовать возможности java fx.
Всвязи с этим возникла идея для обсуждения:
Что, если сделать отдельную компоненту для графика на быстро работающей библиотеке под AWT и с помощью какого-либо средства межпроцессного взаимодействия: rmi, ws, rest скомпоновать его с основным приложением на java fx?
Какие в данном подходе могут быть подводные камни?

Comment: мне кажется что awt и java fx сами по себе не совместимы. Был как-то опыт в контролере добавит `Button`, но он был `awt`. В работе получил эксепшн. Советую разобраться почему глючит javafx с библиотекой jFreeChart. Возможно нужно использовать `Task`-и (потоки)

Answer (score 0):

В рамках текущего вопроса нет необходимости усложнять архитектуру, т.к. `JavaFX` поддерживает отображение `JComponent` (см. [SwingNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html))

Пример под вашу ситуацию:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.block.BlockBorder;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> swingNode.setContent(createChartPanel()));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(swingNode)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ChartPanel createChartPanel() {
        XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
        chartPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

        return chartPanel;
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("2016");
        series.add(18, 567);
        series.add(20, 612);
        series.add(25, 800);
        series.add(30, 980);
        series.add(40, 1410);
        series.add(50, 2350);

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series);

        return dataset;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "Average salary per age",
                "Age",
                "Salary (€)",
                dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
        );

        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();

        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2.0f));

        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);

        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);

        chart.getLegend().setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);

        chart.setTitle(new TextTitle("Average Salary per Age",
                        new Font("Serif", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 18)
                )
        );

        return chart;

    }

}
```

ну и соответственно, не забываем подключить библиотеку:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

P.S.: если же у вас именно при таком подходе приложение тормозит, то:

1. Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону родных графиков JavaFX (см. [руководство](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm))
2. Если данных действительно очень и очень много, то возможно проблема может быть решена улучшением железа. В определении этого вам поможет мониторинг ресурсов.
3. Если пункты 1 и 2 не помогли, то для помощи вам понадобится пример  приложения (который можно запустить и увидеть, что программа действительно тормозит). Соответственно с данными для нагрузки.

P.S.2: В третьем случае не обязательно показывать все ваше приложение (если это запрещено какой либо политикой), достаточно смоделировать данную ситуацию в отдельной новой программе.